# SSRS Report Server Database Locations

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

I've recently inherited management of a large number of SSRS environments.  I'm attempting to generate a list of all the database server/instance/names for each of the SSRS databases (not the data sources).

These are stored in the rsreportserver.config files, but they are encrypted and I'm not sure how to extract them.

Is there an easy way to get this information from a large number of instances?

If there is a way to do it via command line, I can easily push the command to all servers and collect the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found no solution for this.

The "answer" that we are going with is to keep a manually updated list of instances and database names that we have to adjust by hand every time a change is made.

This seems like an incredibly poor design choice by Microsoft to make the data unavailable from any other methods, but if it is retrievable the method does not appear to be documented anywhere.

Thumbs down to the SSRS design team.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx) should do the trick.

> MAP performs a detailed analysis of hardware for migration to Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2, Microsoft Office 2010, and Office 365.

It specifically mentions SQL 2012 at some point, but I guess the same would work for 2008 R2 aswell:

> Discovery of SQL Server 2012 databases, instances, and selected characteristics.

And [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd537572) it says:

> **Detailed reporting:**
>   Covers specific SQL Server instances that include
>   component name, version, edition, and more. Includes wide-ranging
>   details of databases and server instances that can be used for
>   consolidation.

Comment: I've installed and run that against a number of my servers, but it does not appear to give me anything resembling what I was after (SSRS database locations and names).  It mostly just tells me that my servers are ready for update to 2012.

Comment: Did you generate detailed SQL Server reports? See last two steps (14 & 15) on [this link](http://www.handsonsqlserver.com/the-amazing-microsoft-assessment-and-planning-toolkit-map/)

Comment: Oh!  I think I see the confusion.  What you had me do might have worked if the SSRS Instances were on the same servers as the supporting databases, but they are not.  I administrate the SSRS instances, but not the servers with the supporting databases.  I need, though, to get a list of all those supporting databases, preferably using an automated method that I don't have to manually update every time an instance is added/removed/modified, but all I have to work with is the SSRS part, not the actual DB servers.  So, I need the SSRS info, not a list of SQL databases.